# Adding or Updating FormControls to FormGroup in Child Component

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have a scenario where I wanted to add new FormControls in a child component to FormGroup instance in a way that it also updates parent FormGroup instance.

Answer (score -1):

**parent.component.ts**

```
initForm(): void {
   this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        email: new FormControl(''),
        password: new FormControl(false),
   });
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
updateForm (): void {
    let formGroup: FormGroup = null;
    formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
       ...this.formGroup.controls,
       profilePic: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
       ... (Other FormControls you want to add)  
    });

    Object.assign(this.formGroup, formGroup); 
}
```

Comment: This seems like a bad idea to me, why not use addControl?

Comment: It allows us to add multiple controls at one time. Can you please explain why it's not a good practice?

Comment: You're creating a new instance for one

Comment: I made an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-playground-oemzrn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. I forked your example and update it. For makeNew() function, I updated the same instance. Please have a look and share your thoughts. Thanks.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-playground-gfcuvn?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I know it can be done, but you added complexity. You can't predict how other developers will use a form, and you just removed one option from them.